# Combine column value of multiple rows into 1

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to combine the column result of multiple rows into one variable.
A sample of my dataset can be found below.

```
EmailAddress
-------------
myemail@here.com
youremail@here.com
```

Currently, I am using STUFF to combine the `EmailAddress` column into a semicolon delimited list.
A sample can be seen below.

```
SELECT @EmailAddress = CONVERT(nvarchar(max)    
              , STUFF(
                  (SELECT ';' + EmailAddress FROM EmployeeCourseDetails)
                , 1
                , 1
                , '')
              )
```

The desired result should look like `myemail@here.com;youremail@here.com` but when I execute the statement, I get the following error: `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar once with `FOR XML PATH('')`.
Like this:

```
SELECT @EmailAddress = CONVERT(nvarchar(max)    
              , STUFF(
                  (SELECT ';' + EmailAddress FROM EmployeeCourseDetails FOR XML PATH(''))
                , 1
                , 1
                , '')
              )
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for Sekky. Forgot about the For XML Path bit

Answer (score 1):

You can use `COALESCE`:

```
DECLARE @EmailAddress VARCHAR(8000) 

SELECT   @EmailAddress = COALESCE(@EmailAddress + ';', '') + EmailAddress
FROM     EmployeeCourseDetails
ORDER BY EmailAddress

SELECT @EmailAddress
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5503e/1/0)</kbd>

Result: `myemail@here.com;youremail@here.com`